# how rewrite all domains except some to root directory of specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, virtualhost, httpd.conf, directadmin

I have 2 domain on one server.

for example:

a.com & b.com

now I want when a user come in by any another domain example x.ir,y.net,*

apache rewrite it to root of b.com directory.

my panel is directadmin.

now I want to know which file does I must edit and what must write in it ?

**more explain:**

I have a site called b.com now everyone come in and register in it I show him my NameServers and if he have any domain can set my nameservers on their domain.

I have another site on my server called a.com

now I want if anyone come in with his domain except a.com, apache send him to b.com root directory.

Comment: The only way another domain will come into your server is if DNS is pointed to it for that domain. Where are you getting these random domains from?

Comment: other domains comes after setting my server dns in them